# File writing and struct arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, typedef, fwrite

The includes,

```
#include <time.h> /* para calcular data e duracao */
#include <sys/time.h> /* para duracao */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>/* para limpar a tela durante os menus */
#define FILENAME "RelatoriosClimaticos.bin"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

I have a struct defined like this:

```
typedef struct RelatorioClimatico
{ 
    char nomeLocal [50]; 
    struct tm dataColeta;
    int temperatura; 
}RelatorioClimatico;
```

And i have this function that tries to write random values to a binary file:

```
void createRandomFilesByFileSize(FILE *fpp, long int requestedSize)  //Opção 2
{
    struct timeval tm_ini, tm_fim;
    gettimeofday(&tm_ini, NULL);

    long int x=0, registriesNeededForSize, registryBlock;
    int y=0;
    struct tm dataColeta;
    int size = sizeof(RelatorioClimatico);
    RelatorioClimatico *relatorioClimatico = malloc(sizeof(RelatorioClimatico) * 27849);

    registriesNeededForSize = (int)(requestedSize/184);
    registryBlock = (int)(requestedSize/184)/27849;

    rewind(fpp);
    while(x<registryBlock)
    {
        while(y<27849)
        {
            NameGen(relatorioClimatico[y].nomeLocal);
            fflush(stdin);
            relatorioClimatico[y].dataColeta = GeraData();
            fflush(stdin);
            relatorioClimatico[y].temperatura = rand() % 45;
            fflush(stdin);
        }
        x++;
        y=0;
        fseek(fpp, size, SEEK_END);
        fwrite(&relatorioClimatico, size*27849, 1, fpp);
    x++;
    }
    rewind(fpp);


    gettimeofday(&tm_fim, NULL);
    double diff_sec = difftime(tm_fim.tv_sec, tm_ini.tv_sec);
    double diff_milli = difftime(tm_fim.tv_usec, tm_ini.tv_usec)/1000000;

    printf("Os %i relatorios foram gerados em %f segundos, e o arquivo resultando possui %ld bytes \n",registriesNeededForSize, diff_sec+diff_milli, ftell(fpp));

}
```

So what i am not being able to do is to create this typedefined RelatorioClimatico variable:

```
 RelatorioClimatico *relatorioClimatico = malloc(sizeof(RelatorioClimatico) * 27849);
```

Where RelatorioClimatico is the struct, and i want it to be an array of exactly 27849 positions.
I tried this before but it gave me an error:

```
RelatorioClimatico relatorioClimatico[27849];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: *gave me an error*, what error? Post the exact error here.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Please edit your question, adding "...and the error was:  <error message>".  Then we might have a clue what you're talking about.  If it was just a matter of `malloc` returning `NULL`, then my question is, how big is `struct tm`?

Comment: size of that array would be over 2.5 Mb.  How big is your stack?  Was your error a stack overflow?

Comment: @TomKarzes `struct tm` is in `time.h`.  Looks to be 36 bytes

Comment: @ryyker Oh, yeah assuming it's using that version, that makes sense.  It would be nice to see the actual includes.

Comment: Going to put the includes, indeed it uses the time.h struct tm.  Our job is to build a 1gb file, with that struct(RelatorioClimatico), sorry about the indentation, first time posting a question in stackoverflow

Comment: The headers are nice (not sure why you include two locations of time.h though)  Now, can you address the other questions?  Be specific about what error you are getting in particular.

Comment: How can i initialize an array of structs?
Does this work?
RelatorioClimatico relatorioClimatico[27849];
Which would be the same as
struct a/*generic struct*/ = a[100].

Comment: And i do want an array that is able to store exactly 27849 registries, because each registry has 184 bytes of size, and those multiplied equals to 512kb which would be the size of each Fwrite.  
So, i wanted an array that is able to stack 512kb of data, and after filling itself up it writes 512kb to a file, in a loop, repeating itself until the file has the size asked by the user
Sorry if it is confusing, i tried to make myself clear.